# Sushi swap exchange rate question

Tags: exchanges

I found the exchange on sushi swap or uni swap always changing, if I change 1000 usdt to USDC, the rate is better than changing 10000 usdt, usually if you change more, the rate should be better? Why this different?

Answer (score 0):

Uniswap and Sushiswap are automated market makers (AMMs)...

> usually if you change more, the rate should be better?

...but you are comparing them against conventional exchanges.

Specifically, Uniswap and Sushiswap are a type of AMM - a Constant Product Market Maker. Rather than having an order book like conventional exchanges, they use the following formula:

```
x * y = k
```

Where `x` and `y` are the two tokens on either side of the exchange, and `k` is a value that must remain constant. The result of using this formula means that:

> "This formula has the desirable property that larger trades (relative
> to reserves) execute at exponentially worse rates than smaller ones."<sup>1</sup>

Why is such a property desirable? Because larger trades cause a greater change in the ratio of liquidity between the two tokens - you are taking more liquidity from one of the pools, making this market less efficient - so you pay a higher price.

<sup>1</sup>https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/protocol-overview/how-uniswap-works/